# How do I get the iTunes play control widget back in Dashboard?

Tags: itunes, macos, dashboard-widget

In OS X 10.7 Lion, the iTunes dashboard widget from 10.6 Snow Leopard is no longer on the dashboard, I can't find a method of adding it again, it doesn't appear to be listed.

I frequently used this to control play/pause and track forward back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it [here.](http://www.zebpedersen.co.uk/?p=1729)

Comment: Thank you for helping restore my instant access to itunes play functions!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of service.